# Using Conditional Formatting to highlight a cell based on if an adjacent cell is between two values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'd like to turn the background color of cells in column A to RED based on whether adjacent cells in column B contain a value between 1% and 100%.

I'm halfway there...

I was able to turn A1 red by implementing the conditional formatting rule:
$B1 < 100%

AND, I was able to turn A1 red by implementing the conditional formatting rule:
$B1 > 1%

BUT, I haven't been successful when trying to combine both of these rules. I want A1 to turn red when the value of B1 is between 1% and 100%. To me it should be as simple as inputting the rule 100% > $B1 > 1% but this does not seem to work.

Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Thanks in advance for your help!
Sam

Comment: For the conditional formatting, use a formula: `=AND($B1<100%,$B1>1%)`

Comment: @tigeravatar - Yours appears to be the answer, I think it is good to post it as such.

Comment: @tigeravatar - your solution worked perfectly. Thank you! Formulas in Conditional Formatting are constructed differently than they are in the standard function bar?

Comment: It uses the same formula structure as the standard function bar.  You just have to meet two different requirements, so need to use the `AND()` function to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

For the conditional formatting, use a formula: `=AND($B1<100%,$B1>1%)`

(Added as answer instead of comment)